# Dúvida na documentação do kivy, TextInput

Tags: python-3.x, python-kivy, kivy

Na documentação do textinput do kivy tem o seguinte trecho de código

```
def on_enter(instance, value): 
   print('User pressed enter in', instance)

textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world', multiline=False)      
textinput.bind(on_text_validate=on_enter)
```

Isso deve ser posto em que parte do código?
o que seria o instance,value? Instance corresponde ao self? value corresponde ao TextInput.text? O que é esse bind?

Answer (score 0):

Para te demonstrar um exemplo gráfico disso irei usar o FloatLayout, mas pode usar qualquer layout ou widget, e o App, que como deve saber é onde vai ser executado o seu app.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class RootWid(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        # Aqui ela cria a instância para sua caixa de texto, multiline significa
        # múltiplas linhas.
        textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world', multiline=False)

        # A função bind vínculara algo, para quando aquilo acontecer ela chamar uma 
        # função. No exemplo abaixo o textinput é vínculado para quando o texto
        # validar (pressionar "Enter") ele fazer a função on_enter.
        textinput.bind(on_text_validate=self.on_enter)   
        
        # Aqui ele adiciona o textinput a nossa classe
        self.add_widget(textinput)

    # A instance aqui é o self, ou seja, a classe que estamos, e value é
    # a instância de textinput. Você pode usar outros nomes se quiser, botaram
    # na documentação instance e value apenas por convenção
    def on_enter(instance, value):
        print('O usuário pressionou enter e o texto foi: ', value.text, '\na instância 
         é: ', instance)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        rt = RootWid()
        return rt

MyApp().run()
```